# form action is not working properly . it is not moving to the directive link ie < form action="">

Tags: javascript, html

I can't be able to send `form.action="abc.php?mode=save"` on clicking `form.submit();` using Javascript

My java script is:

```
function save()
{
 form.action="abc.php?mode=save";
 form.submit();
}
```

Comment: where is the variable form defined?  Where is it initialized?

Comment: you should also post your HTML so that it can be determined how to access the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `action` dynamically, this is one way:

```
// Add an event listener that fires when a user clicks the "changeButton" button.
document.getElementById("changeButton").addEventListener("click", save);

function save(){
     document.form.action = "/abc.php?mode=save";
     document.form.submit();
}
```

If you are using JQuery, you can create an event listener as follow:

```
$("#changeButton").on("click", save);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="form" id="form">
    <button id="changeButton">Change</button>
</form>
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/hu5334ow/

> **NOTE:**
>
> The `.on()` method was added in JQuery 1.7 version; if your version is lower you must use `.click()` instead.

Comment: will it send form data and mode as save (ie) action="acb.php?made=save&name="value"&age="value"...."  and is it must too send data in post method. and why accept-charset="UTF-8"?

Comment: i dint gave negative vote. can u say how to increase vote. answer is correct only .

Comment: yes i am clicking only . but is says "votes up required 15 reputations" what to do ? . sorry i dint gave negative vote

Comment: Don't worry. Glad to have helped!